# How do I access the filesystem outside of the sandbox on a jailbroken iOS device?

Tags: iphone, ios, jailbreak

I'm going to develop a simple app for jailbroken iOS devices.  I would like to access the filesystem of the device outside of the app's sandbox and move some files (from a directory to another, for example).

How can I do this using Xcode 3.1 or 4, compatible with OS version 3.1.3?

Comment: Have you tried anything and had it not work?

Answer (score 1):

Just use NSFileManager. On a jailbroken device, it gives you full access to the filesystem—just give it the paths you want to mess with. You can get the contents of a directory with its `-contentsOfDirectoryAtPath:error:` method and move files around with `-moveItemAtPath:toPath:error:`.

Comment: I've tried it on a jailbroken device using swift with theos's [application_swift] (means it runs from /Applications), still doesn't work...